# angular animation state mismatch

Tags: angular, animation, state

I'm strugling with animation state of expand/collapse button on the collapsible container.

The state of parent container works as expected, but nested button wont match the state of its container.

To replicate, just expand / collapse the parent container and you'll see that nested button always initializes to expanded state, regardles in what state the container.

link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c2ksiq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcollapsible-container%2Fcollapsible-container.component.ts)

Tried adding initial state in css, played with trigger configurations, stop on debuger to validate the state is correct, many hours on stackoverflow